# Computational Homology used to verify that two spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following two facts seem really intriguing and I am trying to figure out how to use computations of homology to deduce them:

(a) The boundary of an ($n+1$)-simplex is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

(b) An $n$-dimensional convex body is a compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that any two $n$-dimensional convex bodies are homeomorphic.

Any input to help me think about these exercises would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how you could use homology to do either. Homology cannot prove the existence of homeomorphisms in general; it can only prove the non-existence of homeomorphisms. Both statements are true, however, and are easy exercises in _basic_ topology. No input from algebraic topology is required.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was led to think homology should factor in, since these exercises were interlaced with several homology exercises on a problem set from a graduate course. But upon reading through the set again, I noticed that the problems are quite varied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find proofs of both facts in Ch.1 section 16 of Bredon's book *Topology and Geometry.*  Here are the two relevant statements.

**16.3 Proposition**. Let $C\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact convex body with $0\in int(C)$. Then the function $f\colon\partial C\to S^{n-1}$ given by $f(x)=x/||x||$ is a homeomorphism.

This is easy to verify now that you know what the map is!

**16.4 Theorem**. A compact convex body $C$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with nonempty interior is homeomorphic to the closed $n$ ball, and $\partial C\cong S^{n-1}$.

To prove this, assume by translating if necessary that $0\in int(C)$. Define $k\colon D^n\to C$ by $k(x)=||x||f^{-1}(x/||x||)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $k(0)=0$, where $f$ is as above. Now check this is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Not sure why the tex is rendering so poorly.

Answer (score 4):

Homological computations won't help you in proving that two spaces are homeomorphic. Having isomorphic homology groups is (usually) a much weaker condition than being homeomorphic.

In the examples you are interested in, it is possible to write down *explicit* homeomorphisms. My advise would be to try and find these yourself.